# Best way to limit the show count of particular object for an hour?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a web application written on php. I have some objects (represented as rows) in mysql table. And I need to show them randomly during a day.

How can I limit the show count of a particular object, e.g not more than 10 times for an hour?

By the show count I mean how many times the object was rendered.

For example, there are 100 images and with each pageview random 5 are shown. I need to normalize the image shows distribution, by limiting images' show count for an hour, for preventing 1000 shows for one image and 3 to another.

Hope its useful explanation.

Comment: Please give some sample data and explain what you mean with 'show count'.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do it would be to add a field called `last_shown` to your table and then exclude it from the candidate list if it's been shown within the hour.  eg something along these lines:

`SELECT id FROM my_objects WHERE last_shown < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Then when you display that actual object, timestamp the column, ie:

`UPDATE my_objects SET last_shown = NOW() WHERE id = <the_id_you_displayed>`

This approach is simpler, but just as effective. If you reduced the timeframe to once every 6 minutes, it would effectively be similar logic to '10 times within the hour', and not require an entire new reference table.

Comment: If the logic condition is 10 times within an hour, it is not really equivalent to once every 6 minutes - an item could be displayed more 10 times in the first half an hour. In any case, if you use this method, you should add an index on the `last_shown` field otherwise it will do a full table scan every time you select the items.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `log` table with `id` and `date_displayed`.
Each time you select the rows random, you make sure that you select only rows which were not displayed more than 10 times in the last hour.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN ( 
   SELECT id FROM log 
   WHERE date_displayed > now() - interval 1 hour 
   GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
)
ORDER BY rand()
```

Also, after one hour you no longer need older inserts, so you might want to do a DELETE query to remove old records.

```
DELETE FROM log WHERE date_displayed < now() - interval 1 hour
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this approach resource intensive?

Comment: If you delete the older records in the log, it will contain few records, so I don't believe it would have a great impact. You could also add an index on the `date_displayed` field to avoid full table scans. Then, the select from `table` is done fast since you are using a condition on the primary key.